# Do we need to scale output variables when doing gradient descent with multiple variables?

Tags: python, scaling, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient descent algorithm in Python. In lecture of Angrew Ng he said that we have to do feature scaling when implementing Gradient descent with multiple variables. I have implemented scaling function but program predicts wrong. I have scaled all features. Is it required to scale output (target) variables? 

I have seen on internet some people scale all variables including predictions like in this example:
http://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-2/

But Andrew Ng didn't mention about scaling predictions

Comment: Answer for the question can be found here:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re